# Parse.com error message: cloud code socket connection timed out

Tags: parse-platform

I have a parse.com cloud query and  it has started returning "cloud code socket connection timed out" as the result.

It gives this error a code of "124".

Curiously, it does *not* log that a query was called if this error is thrown in the cloud logs, and does *not* log any console.log statements that might be in the query.

Does anybody know what this error means?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use CloudeCode functions? If yes - so CloudCode function request have a 3sec time limit to execution. For background jobs - 15 minutes, as mentioned by @Le Duc Duy.

If you use CloudCode functions or jobs, please share your code so we can consider something.

Here are some examples of custom Function and Background Job:

**Function:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getRecords", function(request, response) {
  importio.getRecords(request, response);
});
```

**Job:**

```
Parse.Cloud.job('populateAllCities', function(request, response){
  //Do job here with 15 mins timeout
  response.success(@"Work done!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-writing
You can only run a background task for only 15 minutes. Running task longer than that will caused timeout

Cloud queries and persistent hooks will have smaller timeout. You can read the doc for more info

[image: 15 minutes background jobs]

Comment: i'm not running a background task. The page you link to does not mention the error code 124 either - are you sure this is related somehow?